# Using Late binding on MSGraph Chart Object

Tags: vba, ms-access

Dear Stackoverflow community,
I don't know if this is correct and would like some guidance on how to use `Late binding` on `MSGraph` object.
I have used this `Early binding` and it works but now I want to use late binding so that I can avoid having to add the `Microsoft Graph 16.0 Object Library`.
The below code works but requires the `Microsoft Graph 16.0 Object Library`

**Early binding:**

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim myChart As Graph.Chart
Dim myChartSeries As Graph.Series
Dim mySeriesDataLabel As Graph.DataLabel

Set myChart = Me.myGraph.Object

For Each myChartSeries In myChart.SeriesCollection

For Each mySeriesDataLabel In myChartSeries.DataLabels
mySeriesDataLabel.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
mySeriesDataLabel.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
mySeriesDataLabel.Font.Size = 8
Next mySeriesDataLabel
Next myChartSeries

With Me.myGraph.Axes(1).TickLabels.Font
.Name = "Times New Romans"
.FontStyle = "Normal"
.Size = 8
End With

 With Me.myGraph.Axes(2).TickLabels.Font
.Name = "Times New Romans"
.FontStyle = "Normal"
.Size = 8
End With

End Sub
```

**Late binding:** -Approach

I have tried this code and seems to be working but I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it.
Could someone please kindly direct me towards the right approach?

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim myChart As Object
Set myChart = Me.myGraph.Object
    
Dim myChartSeries As Variant
Set myChartSeries = New VBA.Collection

Dim mySeriesDataLabel As Variant
Set myChartSeries = New VBA.Collection

For Each myChartSeries In myChart.SeriesCollection

For Each mySeriesDataLabel In myChartSeries.DataLabels
mySeriesDataLabel.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    mySeriesDataLabel.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
mySeriesDataLabel.Font.Size = 8
Next mySeriesDataLabel
Next myChartSeries

With Me.myGraph.Axes(1).TickLabels.Font
    .Name = "Times New Romans"
    .FontStyle = "Normal"
    .Size = 8
End With

With Me.myGraph.Axes(2).TickLabels.Font
    .Name = "Times New Romans"
    .FontStyle = "Normal"
    .Size = 8
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is fine. There are two oddities, here:

```
Dim myChartSeries As Variant '<- Why a Variant? We use Object for late-bound objects
Set myChartSeries = New VBA.Collection 'Why? It's not a collection, and you overwrite this in the For Each
```

If we rewrite that, we're left with:

```
Dim myChart As Object
Set myChart = Me.myGraph.Object
    
Dim myChartSeries As Object
Dim mySeriesDataLabel As Object
'No More Set ... As Collection

For Each myChartSeries In myChart.SeriesCollection
       'Etc...
```

Comment: Nice and Swift. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have amended my code now works well. Sorry I can't answer your questions as I don't know any better.