# Change Font in MS Access Modern Chart

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to change the Font Style of the X and Y Axis Label of a "modern chart" in MS Access. Unfortunately there are no Properties to do so. So i Googled for a solution and found this approach:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim myChart As Graph.Chart
Dim myChartSeries As Graph.Series
Dim mySeriesDataLabel As Graph.DataLabel

Set myChart = Me.myGraph.Object

For Each myChartSeries In myChart.SeriesCollection

For Each mySeriesDataLabel In myChartSeries.DataLabels
mySeriesDataLabel.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
mySeriesDataLabel.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
mySeriesDataLabel.Font.Size = 8
Next mySeriesDataLabel
Next myChartSeries

With Me.myGraph.Axes(1).TickLabels.Font
.Name = "Times New Romans"
.FontStyle = "Normal"
.Size = 8
End With

 With Me.myGraph.Axes(2).TickLabels.Font
.Name = "Times New Romans"
.FontStyle = "Normal"
.Size = 8
End With

End Sub
```

Source: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451291/using-late-binding-on-msgraph-chart-object)

Because of my reputation, I am not able to comment the linked topic, hence I have created this new question.

While searching the internet for a solution i have mentioned that i am not the only one who can't

`Set myChart = Me.myGraph.Object`

because Access is telling me that my Graph has no Method or Attribute like `.Object`.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I set up the reference in Access VBA to Microsoft Graph 16.0 Object Library.

Comment: The example code you cited is for classic MSGraph, not Modern Chart.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr: As far as I know + see, you are out of luck.**

Modern Charts are completly different from "old" charts and use a different object model, that's why your code fails.

Now let's have a look into "modern" charts:
For whatever reasons, lots of things that you would expect are not possible. That's not an issue with VBA, it's an issue with Access itself. Try to modify the fonts manually (in Access): You will see that there is no font property for the single elements (except for the title). You simply cannot change the font for an axis or any other element (except for the chart title and subtitle). You can modify the color and the size, but not the font itself.

In VBA, usually you can do exact what is possible with the application itself.  Sometimes not everything if MS forgot to expose some properties or methods, only in very few cases you can do more than the application offers (because at the end of the day, the VBA code uses the objects that are provided by the application.

To use a (modern) chart in VBA, use the type `Chart` (`Access.Chart`, to be precise). Playing around with it:

```
Dim ch As Access.Chart
Set ch = Me.myGraph
ch.ChartTitleFontName = "Arial"
ch.PrimaryValuesAxisFontColor = vbRed
```

You can use the debugger to have a look at the details (for example using the Locals Window), or use the object browser to dig into the properties and methods of the chart class, but you will find no way to change the fonts except for the title.